# Understanding Fluid flow- Am I right or the book?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

I was solving this question :-

[image]

And according to Me H=10cm is the answer.

But the book says this:-

[image]

Now , I don't understand **why does the liquid fall quickly on reaching top right corner?? **

One reason I could think of was because of capillary action (since radius of tube << 10 cm).
But in that case , I don't see how an air column would be created? I guess vacuum would be created instead which would be quickly filled with water behind.

What do you think??

Comment: Would you please rotate the second picture so it can be read easily?

Comment: @cms no, op should instead *copy* the text into the post directly so that it can be indexed by search engines and read by all users.

Answer (score 1):

If the flow is sufficiently slow enough to facilitate a partial flow in the top horizontal limbs of the glass tube, it must allow the partial flow until all the vertical glass limbs are filled with water( Note that partial flow is the reason for air traps). So from the question we cannot assume a situation in which alternate vertical limbs being filled with air column. Also note that in such type of flows(in which water velocity is very small) air(which is having negligible density as compared to water)will always try to stay on top( ie in the upper portion of top horizontal limbs). So the configuration given in the hint does not conform to the given situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct and the book is wrong.

Trapping of air in the glass tube is not inevitable. Even if air was trapped due to partial flow in the beginning (as Jithin pointed out), you still need a pressure head in the rubber tube only slightly greater than $h=10$ cm to drive the flow of water through the glass tube. The flow may be partial (i.e. the air gap may not be eliminated) but there will be flow.

Suppose that were not the case; say there was no flow from the end $C$ even when the water head in the rubber tube $H>h$, say for $H=20$ cm. Since water is at rest, constant pressure surfaces are horizontal (capillary effects neglected). This means that pressure at top of every section of the glass tube must be equal to that in the rubber tube at the same level, which is equal to $p_0+\rho g(H-h)>p_0$, in which $p_0$ is atmospheric pressure. This above-atmospheric pressure must drive water in the last column, because right end of it (near end $C$) is exposed to atmospheric pressure while its left end is exposed to above-atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score 0):

This is truly a nightmare question, based on some tricky aspects of the situation. You have my sympathy, but the answer is correct.

You're considering the case when the entire tube is full of fluid. And your answer is right for that.

But that specific situation they described results in pressurizing the air trapped in the top of the squares.  Note that the levels are not the same from one leg to the next:  There's air pressure in the top of each tube.  That pressure is higher as you go from right to left, highest in the first tube.  And H has to be big enough to push water against that pressure plus gravity.